Sign message does not work using Coinbase Wallet on iOS Safari
I'm having problem with Coinbase Wallet on iOS (did not tested for other devices, but I assume it's the same issue).
Basically, I'm able to connect wallet using Coinbase, but when I try so Sign, I get error 'UnknownRpcError'.
I'm using wagmi useSignMessage and it works perfectly with Metamask, but only mobile Coinbase wallet app does not throw popup asking for Sign.
I've checked MagicEden Connect Wallet flow and looks like they have it sovled
As well for connector I'm using RainbowConnect, and for Signing message - Wagmi package
I've tried eth library, tried debugging and it throws same error.

Is this in a programming context?
